# Fetch random rows with limit on values

Tags: mysql

My table is like

Table:

```
id    col1 col2
0      a    0
1      a    0
2      a    1
3      a    0
```

I want random values of col2 from table

I want result like

```
id 0,1,2
```

Means if a value is 0 then there should be only 2 rows for value 0 only not more than that

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest method is to use `union all`:

```
(select t.*
 from t
 where col2 = 0
 order by rand()
 limit 2
) union all
(select t.*
 from t
 where col2 <> 0
 order by rand()
);
```

Comment: i want random values

Comment: because col2 values are not limited it might be 0 to 10

Comment: and i want 10 random rows with values that not repeated more than  3 times

Comment: @user3045586 . . . Your desired result did not really say "random results".